# Problem with constructors and inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I am having the following problem:

```
public class A {
    public A(X, Y, Z) {
    ...
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public B(X, Y) : base(X, Y) {
        //i want to instantiate Z here and only then pass it to the base class!
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way?

Comment: What? is `B:A`? If so, how can A have *more* data than B? Also, A doesn't seem to have such a constructor...

Comment: Do you mean public class B : A { in your example?

Comment: Edited original post. Yes, its B: A

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The common solution is to call a static method belonging to the type that can calculate the value of the parameter to be passed to the base constructor.

For example:

```
public B(int x, int y)
    : base(x, y, CalculateZ(x, y))
{

}

// You can make this parameterless if it does not depend on X and Y
private static int CalculateZ(int x, int y)
{
   //Calculate it here.

    int exampleZ = x + y;

    return exampleZ;
}
```

Do note that `CalculateZ` cannot be an instance method, because the `this` reference is not available in constructor initializers.

From the language-specification 10.11.1 Constructor initializers:

> An instance constructor initializer
>   cannot access the instance being
>   created. Therefore it is a
>   compile-time error to reference this
>   in an argument expression of the
>   constructor initializer, as is it a
>   compile-time error for an argument
>   expression to reference any instance
>   member through a simple-name.

EDIT: Changed 'instance' to 'static' in the description.

Comment: +1, but don't you mean that it's legal to call *static* methods?

Comment: @Kobi, @LukeH: Was a brain-freeze typo; the mind thinks one thing and the fingers type another. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate Z before the constructor itself gets called. If it's simple you can use an inline expression, else you'll need to define a helper function.

Using a helperfunction:

```
public class A {
    public A(X x, Y y, Z z) {
    ...
    }
}

public class B : A {
    private static Z calculateZ()
    {
    }

    public B(X x, Y y) : base(X, Y, calculateZ()) {

    }
}
```

Without helperfunction:

```
public B(X, Y) : base(X, Y, X+Y) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class A {
    public A(X, Y) {
    ...
    }

    public abstract Z TheVariableZ{get;set;}
}

public class B : A {
    public B(X, Y) : base(X, Y) {
        //i can only calculate Z here!
    }

    public override Z TheVariableZ{//implement it here}
}
```

And if you can't make A abstract, just mark the property as virtual

Comment: Calling a virtual method in a constructor is a bad idea: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this:

```
public abstract class A {
    public A(X, Y) {
       CalculateZ();
    }

    abstract void CalculateZ();
}

public class B : A {
    public B(X, Y) : base(X, Y) {

    }

    override void CalculateZ()
   {
      ... Calculate here.
   }
}
```

Comment: Calling a virtual method in a constructor is a bad idea: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331(v=VS.100).aspx